# Javascript and Ajax - Including a calledback variable in an interval

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, intervals

Having the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chargeup = 0;
var flag1 = "no";
var stored = <?php print $x_row['watts']; ?>; // Gets wstored (previous value) from DB.
var charge = <?php print $charge; ?> + stored;
window.onload = function chargeT1() {
timer = setInterval(function chargeT2 () {
    charge = charge+<?php print $n_gr; ?>; // $n_gr = 1; 
        if (flag1 !="no"){
            charge = chargeup;
        }
    document.getElementById('charge').innerHTML = charge;
    flag1 = "no";
}, 1000);
}
</script>
```

We get a "timer" that adds +1, since $n_gr = 1, every second.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want to return a "flag1='yes';" and a new "chargeup" value from a callback function that would change the variable "charge" to "chargeup" and continue adding +1 every second.

*For example: In moment "t" the value of charge is "100", in "t+1" is 101, in "t+2" is 102,... An event triggers the callback function and returns "chargeup = 10" and "flag1=yes" so "charge" changes to 10 and keeps adding +1 every second from 10: t+3 is 11, t+4 is 12...*

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when the callback function returns, for example, 10 I get that charge is 10, then 101,1011,10111...

This is my callbackfunction:

```
function useHttpResponse (){
   if (http.readyState == 4) {
      if (http.status == 200) { 
      var timeWatts = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("upwatts")[0];
      chargeup = timeWatts.childNodes[0].nodeValue; //example: returns a value of 10
      flag1 = "yes";
      } else {
         document.getElementById('showbuy').innerHTML='<img src="anim.gif">';
             }
      }
  }
```

I'm really stuck. Any ideas or suggestions will be very welcomed. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `chargeUp` is a string, so `charge` is a string, and `(string)charge + (int)$n_gr` => `string`. This is what happens when JavaScript weak typing meets overloaded `+`.

This can be repaired by using a numeric coercion somewhere. Change one of the following lines to

```
charge = +charge + +<?php print $n_gr; ?>;
```

or

```
charge = +chargeup; // my recommendation
```

(Unary `+` is the approved JS idiom for cast-to-number.)

Comment: It works! Thank you so so much! I was getting crazy over this small problem. The explanation helped me to understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    charge = charge+<?php print $n_gr; ?>; // $n_gr = 1;
```

to

```
    charge = (+charge)+(+<?php print $n_gr; ?>); // $n_gr = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. That was exactly what I was doing wrong.